# CSS-How do you reference an image on the user's computer?

Tags: html, css, png

I am working on a website which I don't own, but I was asked to change the .PNG file for the footer.  I have made the changes on the .PNG, and was wondering if there was a way that I could view the source in my browser and change the url(images/image.png) to reference my version.

Comment: If you want to "update" the current page's content, use Firebug of Chrome Console.

Answer (score 5):

The only way I can think of would be to host your image online (think [imageshack.us](http://imageshack.us) or something similiar) and then use the Firefox plug in called Firebug to change the CSS file to look at the online hosted image instead of the one it is originally looking at.

Comment: I guess I was a little vague.  I was just trying to change it temporarily in my browser to get a feel for what it will look like, and to save them the trouble of changing the image just to find out they don't like how it looks.

Comment: @user1031369 I've fixed it. This should answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

If you are viewing the local HTML file from the computer (i.e. the file on the hard drive, via the `file://` protocol) then a relative URL will "just work".

Otherwise, no.

*If you try something like `background:url(file:///Users/phrogz/Desktop/dot.png)` you will see: "Not allowed to load local resource" in your Console.*